# c# constructor injection and constructor overloads

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor, inversion-of-control

I'm using constructor injection for the first time and wish to write my code defensively.

Therefore if I have a class with a constructor and a save method as below:

```
public SomeConstructor(string name, Object someObject)
{
  _name= name;
  _someObject= someObject;
}

public void Save()
{
  // Does a database save
}
```

But then need to create another related method in this Class that doesn't need the _someObject so I create an overloaded chained constructor as:

```
public SomeConstructor(string name) : this(name, null)
{
}
```

How can I successfully stop someone instantiating the class with this second constructor with 1 parameter and using the Save() which has someObject as null?

I'm not using an injection tool.

Above is a simple example and in it, you are correct I could just throw an exception for a null just as I would if a property was not set.

What I wanted to avoid was a series of validation checks at the start of each method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the friction you are experiencing as a **warning system**. It's really telling you that you're likely moving towards low [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

If this is the case, refactor the class into two separate classes.

Comment: But in the example above you would basically have 1 class to save/delete an object with it being passed in the constructor. I.e. 1 class just for Persistence? All other methods such as Get() the most recent SomeObject would require a seperate class? That kinda sounds like overkill?

Comment: Sometimes it's overkill, but then you could just accept that one of the arguments passed to the constructor isn't used in all cases.

Comment: mmm... I guess there isn't always a best approach. Programming defensively means taking decisions which might violate some of your other 'principles'. I guess I was just hoping for 1 overriding rule for all situations.

Comment: Adding a second constructor that allows one or more fields to remain null can hardly be called defensive coding...

Comment: Hence the question in the first place: "How can I successfully stop someone instantiating the class with this second constructor with 1 parameter and using the Save() which has someObject as null?"

Comment: Add a Guard Clause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189628/private-readonly-interface-is-it-redundant/6190678#6190678

Answer (score 1):

You may prevent that situation with a run-time exception like InvalidOperationException.

If some instantiated the class with the two-parameters-constructor and tries to call Save, just check if "someObject" is null, and if it's so:

`throw new InvalidOperationException("This method cannot be invoked in current object state");`

In the other hand, if this second constructor would be used by your library and third-party library developers wouldn't be allowed to use it, this constructor should have the internal modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Save()
{  
    if (_someObject == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

I guess that this is obvious. But you really can't create a contract in which the type is constructed differently unless you also change your `SomeConstructor` type to work like a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). What the decorator pattern does is that it let's you build the inheritance hierarchy at run-time not compile-time.

You can then create different objects depending on what operations are allowed internally. This is some work for something which can easily be handled with a pre-condition for the `Save` method. But maybe this is what you need. And if you did it you could stipulate your contract in the constructor of `SomeConstructor`.

Here's an example:

```
interface ISomeConstructor
{
    void Save();
}

class SomeConstructor
{
    ISomeConstructor impl;

    public SomeConstructor(string name, object someObject)
    {
        impl = new StringAndObject(name, someObject);
    }

    public SomeConstructor(string name)
    {
        impl = new JustString(name);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        impl.Save();
    }
}
```

The types `StringAndObject` and `JustString` implements `ISomeConstructor` and they can handle the `Save` method as they see fit.

This is a slight variation of the decorator pattern as normally you'd expect `ISomeConstructor` to be passed as an argument to the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

The IoC it is just a way to dinamically resolve the dependency but doens't solve any OO problem.
I would focus on a good OO design instead of try to find a way to cheat the framework forcing to use a contractor instead of another.The question is how would you do that if you were not using an IoC framework?
probabily checking if SomeObject is null?